# onClick not firing within map - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've searched around and thought I had found a solution. However, my code just doesn't seem to fire the 'handleClick' function via onClick. At first I thought it was a scope issue, so I passed 'this' into the map which fixes the console error but the function never fires...

If I move the button outside of the map it works, no errors are being thrown.

```
    handleClick: function(event) {
       console.log('Clicked');
       this.setState({personName: 'Hello'});
    },

     render: function () {
       var text = this.state.personName;
       var parsedItems = this.state.userItems.map(this.prepareData);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onclick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</button>   <---- This works
            <div className="row hidden-xs">
                <div className="loading"></div>
                {
                    parsedItems.map(function (itemData, index) {
                        return (
                            <div key={itemData.itemCode}>
                                <p>{text}</p>
                                <p><button onclick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</button></p>  <-- This doesn't work
                            </div>
                        )
                    }, this)
                }
           )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the down voting but I did find a solution to this in the end. Just in case anyone else comes across this, the **onclick** is case sensitive so needs to be **onClick** this doesn't throw any errors which is annoying!